# Route paths with or without of trailing slashes in rust/axum

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I want to route both `http://0.0.0.0/foo` and `http://0.0.0.0/foo/` to the same `get_foo` handler. However, in practice, only `/foo` gets routed and `/foo/` 404s. I suspect I'm setting up/attaching the middleware wrong:

```rust
use axum::http::StatusCode;
use axum::{routing::{get}, Router};
use std::{net::SocketAddr};
use tower_http::normalize_path::NormalizePathLayer;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/foo", get(get_foo))
        .layer(NormalizePathLayer::trim_trailing_slash());

    let port_str = std::env::var("PORT").unwrap_or("8000".to_owned());
    let port = port_str.parse::<u16>().unwrap();
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([0, 0, 0, 0], port));
    println!("listening on http://{}", addr);
    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn get_foo() -> Result<String, StatusCode>  {
    Ok("Hello from foo.".to_owned())
}
```

... and accompanying `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "axum_trailing_slash"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
axum = { version = "0.6" }
tokio = { version = "1.0", features = ["full"] }
tower = { version = "0.4" }
tower-http = { version = "0.3", features = ["normalize-path"] }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs of [`Router::layer`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Router.html#method.layer):

> Middleware added with this method will run after routing and thus cannot be used to rewrite the request URI. See [“Rewriting request URI in middleware”](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/middleware/index.html#rewriting-request-uri-in-middleware) for more details and a workaround.

> The workaround is to wrap the middleware around the entire Router (this works because Router implements Service):

```rust
//…
use axum::ServiceExt;
use tower::layer::Layer;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app =
        NormalizePathLayer::trim_trailing_slash().layer(Router::new().route("/foo", get(get_foo)));
    //…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Version without an additional dependency or middleware:

```
trait RouterExt<S, B>
where
    B: HttpBody + Send + 'static,
    S: Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    fn directory_route(self, path: &str, method_router: MethodRouter<S, B>) -> Self;
}

impl<S, B> RouterExt<S, B> for Router<S, B>
where
    B: HttpBody + Send + 'static,
    S: Clone + Send + Sync + 'static,
{
    fn directory_route(self, path: &str, method_router: MethodRouter<S, B>) -> Self {
        self.route(path, method_router.clone())
            .route(&format!("{path}/"), method_router)
    }
}
```

Then add routes like `let app = Router::new().directory_route("/foo", get(get_foo)`.
It will add both the `/foo` and `/foo/` routes.